# Top row of Stripe PaymentElement not showing

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe into a React app and everything works but I can't seem to get the top row to show up: [image: sample PaymentElement img]

What am I missing?

Comment: We don't know what you're missing, because your question is missing your code 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Likely you haven't set [automatic_payment_methods.enabled=true](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-automatic_payment_methods-enabled), or passed in the list of payment methods you want to manually enable in [payment_method_types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_types) when creating the PaymentIntent.

Comment: This was it. I was assuming it was something I had to do on the client-side but had to add more options on the server side and from the example I pulled from, the only type was 'card'.